# Exclude activity from recent apps list

Tags: android, android-activity

From widget I want to start an activity to create a checklist, note, or task and then exclude it from recent apps on successful creation.
How do I Exclude an activity from recent apps list(only when I start it from widget?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `android:excludeFromRecents="true`. Use it in your manifest

or

Also you can use flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS:

```
//when you startActivity add this flag
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
startActivity(intent);
```

The activity you start won't be in recent apps.